# Syntax error in CQL query (Cassandra CQL COPY FROM command): "mismatched input"

Tags: cassandra, cql

I receive the following error when I attempt to load a CSV file, delimited by tabs, into a Cassandra table:

> ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:747
>   mismatched input '-800' expecting ')' (... facebook,'2014-01-01
>   00:00:00',0,'0',1[-800]-...)" Aborting import at record #1. Previously
>   inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be
>   present as well.

The file is a 62-column tab-separated file that I'm attempting to load in via the following statement

```
COPY alpha_table 
(a,al,e,p,b,ag,ab,au,l,m,aq,aw,g,af,am,s,aj,aa,ad,ak,ah,h,be,y,bh,z,ay,az,as,bi,av,n,v,ac,k,j,x,ax,f,ao,an,o,u,d,ai,bf,ap,bg,i,ar,c,t,bd,bj,at,bc,ba,bb,ae,r,w,q) 
FROM '/tmp/data.csv' WITH DELIMITER='\t'
```

The table has a mix of int and text fields as follows

```
CREATE TABLE alpha_table ( a int PRIMARY KEY, al text, e int, p text, b int, ag text, ab int, au text, l int, m int, aq text, aw int, g text, af int, am text, s int, aj text, aa int, ad int, ak int, ah text, h text, be text, y int, bh int, z text, ay int, az int, as int, bi int, av int, n text, v int, ac int, k text, j text, x int, ax int, f text, ao text, an text, o int, u int, d text, ai text, bf text, ap int, bg int, i text, ar int, c text, t int, bd text, bj text, at text, bc int, ba int, bb int, ae int, r text, w int, q text)
```

The data file has 100 records which differ only in respect to the id in the first column and are otherwise identical.

```
1000001 "30214" "Abe's House of Chow"   "Abe's House of Chow"   1   "N" "Macon Mall's newest restaurant, Abes House of Chow is holding its official grand opening October 1 2014. City leaders and the owners of the restaurant will gather for the ribbon cutting ceremony as they expect more than more than 500 people at the event. The restaurant sells nearly 8 thousand pulled pork sandwiches a week."  "0" "never leave hungry"    "free wings if you like us on facebook" "2014-01-01 00:00:00"   "0" "0" "1-800-CHOWDWN" 5   "kia"   "f8FJdaM1dYE"   "0" 1   1   1   0   0   0   "0" "HU"    "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "30"    "0" "abes-house-of-chow"    "Y94L"  "#abeshouseofchow"  0   "2012-06-14 00:00:00"   "2015-03-16 15:20:44"   "2014-01-11 11:15:58"   "abe"   "-3"    "0" 8   "0" "C" "2012-06-14 00:00:00"   "0" "0" "0" 1   1   1   1   "0" "N" "en"    "U" 0
```

The strange thing about this error is that when I try to insert all 100, I get the error but if I create a new file with just the first 20, I don't.  Strangely, either way, it will say that the records were inserted whether they were or not.

> cqlsh:alpha_keyspace> COPY alpha_table
>   (a,al,e,p,b,ag,ab,au,l,m,aq,aw,g,af,am,s,aj,aa,ad,ak,ah,h,be,y,bh,z,ay,az,as,bi,av,n,v,ac,k,j,x,ax,f,ao,an,o,u,d,ai,bf,ap,bg,i,ar,c,t,bd,bj,at,bc,ba,bb,ae,r,w,q)
>   FROM '/tmp/data_100.csv' WITH DELIMITER='\t';
>
> ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:747
>   mismatched input '-800' expecting ')' (... facebook,'2014-01-01
>   00:00:00',0,'0',1[-800]-...)" Aborting import at record #1. Previously
>   inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be
>   present as well.
>
> 100 rows imported in 0.126 seconds.
>
> cqlsh:alpha_keyspace> COPY alpha_table
>   (a,al,e,p,b,ag,ab,au,l,m,aq,aw,g,af,am,s,aj,aa,ad,ak,ah,h,be,y,bh,z,ay,az,as,bi,av,n,v,ac,k,j,x,ax,f,ao,an,o,u,d,ai,bf,ap,bg,i,ar,c,t,bd,bj,at,bc,ba,bb,ae,r,w,q)
>   FROM '/tmp/data_20.csv' WITH DELIMITER='\t';
>
> 20 rows imported in 0.122 seconds

I'm using cqlsh 5.0.1 against my local Cassandra 2.1.8 instance.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.